# Validation question for App ID 42949683061

Tags: office-store

I submitted a Word app for doing code syntax highlighting, but it has been rejected because the word "test" was not highlighted when the tester was trying out the app.

The app has several different themes available, and recognises many different programming languages. 'test' is not a keyword in any of the offered languages, and so the correct behaviour of the app is that the word 'test' in that context should not be highlighted.

The app has instructions included, and also has code snippets that can be transferred to the word document to be used as examples or for testing purposes.

Please could I request that someone takes another look at this app as I believe it is working correctly and has clear instructions, but in this case the tester misunderstood the expected behaviour of their actions.

Many thanks,

Tony

Answer (score 0):

I just resubmitted it with some testing notes.